# How to visualise means with Seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-visualization, heatmap

I have a Pandas data frame with the following structure:

```
     alpha  beta  gamma       mse
0     0.00  0.00   0.00  0.000000
1     0.05  0.05   0.90  0.025411
2     0.05  0.10   0.85  0.025794
3     0.05  0.15   0.80  0.026289
4     0.05  0.20   0.75  0.025320
..     ...   ...    ...       ...
148   0.75  0.05   0.20  0.026816
149   0.75  0.10   0.15  0.025817
150   0.75  0.15   0.10  0.025702
151   0.80  0.05   0.15  0.027104
152   0.80  0.10   0.10  0.025936
```

I would like to visualise the data frame with a heatmap where alpha is represented on the x-axis, beta is represented on the y-axis, and for each square of the lattice, the mean MSE over all gammas is computed. Is there an easy way to do this by using Seaborn?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I still don't understand `gamma` and `mse`. You have a 2D map with `alpha`-`beta`. It seems for each square of 0.05 x 0.05 you have two numbers: `gamma` and `MSE of all gammas??`. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

For what you showed, yes, you can do with:

```
sns.heatmap(df.pivot_table(index='beta', columns='alpha', values='mse'))
```

Answer (score 0):

All the calculation should be done in your DataFrame.
Once you have the data, you could use pivoted DataFrame to build the heatmap

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# Assuming that you have the df variable with your data

# pivot the data
pivoted = df.pivot('alpha', 'beta', 'mse')

# plot the heatmap
sns.heatmap(pivoted, annot=True)
plt.show()
```

More information in the official documentation: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html